# Getting remote data from JSON API using Axios and Vue

Tags: json, vue.js, axios

I'm very much at the beginning of my journey with Vue and JSON and I'm trying the following as an example.

I'm getting data from tastedive.com like so:

```
https://tastedive.com/api/similar?q=cannibal+corpse
```

Which gives me this:

```
{
  "Similar": {
    "Info": [
      {
       "Name": "Cannibal Corpse",
      "Type": "music"
   }
 ],
 "Results": [
  {
    "Name": "Death",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Deicide",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Carcass",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Slayer",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Morbid Angel",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Sepultura",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Nile",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Dying Fetus",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Behemoth",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Six Feet Under",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Lamb Of God",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Vader",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Bloodbath",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Amon Amarth",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Obituary",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Aborted",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Immortal",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Dark Funeral",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Kreator",
    "Type": "music"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Decapitated",
    "Type": "music"
  }
]
}
}
```

Using the following in a file called app.js

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  results: []
},
mounted() {
 axios.get("https://tastedive.com/api/similar?q=cannibal+corpse")
.then(response => {this.results = response.data.results})
 }
});
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-xxl">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
<div class="container" id="app">
  <div class="" v-for="result in results">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-divider">
            {{ result.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="card-section">
            <p>{{ result.type }}.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, I'm not getting any results to the page.

Any guidance or help on what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

The main issue was pathing

```
response.data.results
```

Should've read:

```
response.data.Similar.Results
```

To reflect the JSON structure.

As noted in a comment below, I am getting CORS errors. I signed up for an API Key which hasn't fixed that issue. I have contacted tastedive.com asking them if they have any guidance on how to resolve this. I am using a browser plugin to get round the issue locally (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc)

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Does it throw any errors? Also, can you do a console.log on `response` to see if there is even data in `data.results`?

Comment: No, no errors, just nothing to the screen (except the 'hello world'). How would I amend my code to add a console.log? Thanks.

Comment: Change this `{this.results = response.data.results}` to this `{this.results = response.data.results; console.log(response)};` to log the data in your (browser) console. Then you can inspect the response directly in your browser and see what data is coming.

Comment: And just as a note, tried to access the API with axios from a JS Fiddle and I get a CORS error. So maybe they have restricted the access from outside, also on this page `https://tastedive.com/read/api` they are writing something about an API key you need in order to fully access their api

Comment: `this.results = response.data.results` should be `this.results = response.data.Results` to match the actual data.

Comment: I've edited my question to update progress.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the original question with the answer.